# Merge JSON Files (Newtonsoft.Json.JsonReaderException)

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am trying to merge FILE 2 into FILE 1. 
I cant seem to come right with my code and I suspect I am not declaring the JSON files properly. I keep getting an error - see below

[image]

MY CODE:

```
string DestinationFile = @"C:\Lang Compare\Original\language.json";
string ImportFile = @"C:\Lang Compare\New\language.json";

                JObject FileObject1 = JObject.Parse(DestinationFile);
                   JObject FileObject2 = JObject.Parse(ImportFile);

                FileObject1.Merge(FileObject2, new JsonMergeSettings
                                {
                                    MergeArrayHandling = MergeArrayHandling.Union
                                });

                string FinalJson = FileObject1.ToString();
                        MessageBox.Show(FinalJson);
```

JSON FILE 1

```
{
    "AverageChipStackTitle": "筹码中位数 ",
    "MedianChipStackTitle": "中位数堆",
}
```

JSON FILE 2

```
{
    "AverageChipStackTitle": "堆平均值 %NEW%",
    "MedianChipStackTitle": "堆中位数 %NEW%",
    "TargetChipStackTitle": "目标筹码堆",

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not reading the files, you're parsing the filenames as JSON. The exception clearly mentions the unexpected character `C` at position 0, being the start of `C:\Lang...`.

Read the files instead:

```
JObject FileObject1 = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText(DestinationFile));
JObject FileObject2 = JObject.Parse(File.ReadAllText(ImportFile));
```